# only 96GB of ~750GB after mounting to /home/....?

Tags: partitioning, mount, gparted

I got a 800 GB partition out of a 3 TB HDD, fomated it with ext4 and mounted it to `/home/elliot/BigData` permanently via `/etc/fstab`.
It works fine but after rebooting I got only 96GB free space out of the 800GB the rest turned to used space!

Reformated and tried again, I got the same result.
What went wrong? Where is the rest of my space?

[image: Screenshot of Gparted]

UPDATE:
when i mount the same partition to e.g. /media/test via /etc/fstab i get the full diskspace.... i tried it again with an other folder in the home-directory and again got only 96GB! O_o  Are there any restiction or a kind of an contingent when i mount something to /home/username/somefolder ????

Comment: Are there files in the folder?

Comment: yes, but just the folder i created afterwards for my Lteamlibrary. The library uses now 2GB and now I only have 94GB left...

Comment: Apparently you manged to fill it with 650 gb of data.

Comment: no ....  impossible in 2-5 minutes/1 reboot

Answer (score 1):

Start a shell and type

```
du /home/elliot/BigData
```

This will return the used space, as caulculated by the files that exist on the partition. You can append `-h` for human readable and `-s` for summary.

Per your comment, it's only showing 6.1GB used so something seems to be wrong with the partition. You can attempt to fix this with `fsck`. You need to unmount the volume to do this:

```
sudo umount /dev/sda4
sudo fsck /dev/sda4
```

However if this is your main Linux partition, you won't be able to do this from a running instance. You'll need to boot into a LiveCD/USB. Run `sudo lsblk` to find the partition name (which will be different from `/dev/sda4` in the live environment) and run the `fsck`.

Comment: du /home/elliot/BigData/ -hs

6,1G /home/elliot/BigData/